# Make changes to database values using mathematical function

Tags: database, codeigniter

I would like to make changes to our companies web server database that takes in Integer values from machines and updates them on our reports page on the website.

[This picture shows the report generated on our website and the values for current and voltages are mathematically incorrect as these values need to be divided by 10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJS2D.png)

Our database is on phpmyadmin and we are using codeignitor. Can anyone tell me how can I do a simple mathematical query on the present database values?

Comment: I feel the proper solution is to store the proper values in the first place unless you have a good reason not to. Perhaps it's this way because of difficulty working with decimal numbers or some such, which should be solved rather than worked around. Anyway, MySQL can do arithmetic on results or you can usually manipulate results on your page for display (although I don't know anything about codeignitor or whether it can be modified for this). For instance, as part of your MySQL query you can just use the division function `SELECT current/2 FROM logtable;`